# ArcGIS Engine BaseTool derived classes stops receiving OnKeyDown messages?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I have two BaseTool derived classes in a custom ArcGIS Engine application. Both tools do the same thing: start a INewBezierCurveFeedback on a first mouse click and then stop it and return the resulting polyline on a second mouse click. Both also have "Overrides Sub OnKeyDown" handlers to allow users to "cancel" the tool by pressing the Escape key.

**Test Scenario:**
Start with Tool #1, click on the map to start the line feedback and press the escape key and OnKeyDown gets fired, great! Do it again and get same result.

**Problem:**
Now select Tool #2, and repeat. I don't get the OnKeyDown message here. Go back to Tool #1 and not longer get it there either! I can also reverse this test, starting with Tool #2 and produce the same results.

What's going on here?